# How to Configure Webhooks to Work with Previews on Vercel

Tags: next.js, webhooks, vercel

I am using Vercel to deploy a Next.js app. This app contains backend code that listens for events from third-party services via webhooks, such as the user creation event from Clerk.

To do this, I need to configure the webhook endpoint on these third-party services to specify where I want the events to be sent.

Vercel offers a service named [Previews](https://vercel.com/features/previews), which generates preview builds every time a new commit is pushed to a remote branch configured with Vercel. I would like the webhooks to function with these preview builds, even though these builds generate random URLs.

Is there a way for these preview apps to still receive webhooks?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a full answer to this but I'm in a similar situation where I want to test stripe payment webhooks and found two approaches that might help you too: 1) create a stable webhook that handles your backend logic regardless in what preview environment you are in (assuming your preview envs share the same database and your backend code doesn't change between preview builds) 2) programatically create a new webhook on every deployment and register it with your third-party (i.e. for stripe https://docs.stripe.com/api/webhook_endpoints/create)